# Add extra text to a string if it's long enough

Tags: ruby, string

I want to add an ellipsis `...` to a string if the string is more than `N` characters long. For example, for `N = 11`,

```
ellipse_if_necessary('Hello') # => "Hello"
ellipse_if_necessary('Hello world, how are you') # => "Hello world..."
```

What is the simplest way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with a quick-if:

```
string.length > 30 ? string[0..30]+'...' : string
```

Or a more "ruby way" using an if statement:

```
string = string[0..30] + '...' if string.length > 30
```

in this second example if the string is shorter or equal to 30 characters then it's left untouched.

or another way (as @marimaf pointed out) is to use the `truncate` method:

```
string.truncate(30)
```

Comment: But the first one can give you a one liner result whereas the second one must include a return statement.

Comment: There's a ruby method for this, check my answer

Comment: But here you are assuming that Ruby = Rails (but that was my case, anyway)

Answer (score 2):

```
"some string".sub(/(.{31,})/, '\1...')
```

Comment: I've tried that one and didn't work if you try it with N < string.length it only shows the ellipsis.

Comment: @Lomefin Sorry. I fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

My first thought was of

```
"#{string[0..30]}#{'...' if string.length > 30}"
```

But the first quick-if from @Macmee looks very good, and I guess is less expensive than my proposal.

Answer (score 0):

There is a rails method that does what you need, its called [truncate](http://apidock.com/rails/String/truncate)

It works like this, lets say N = 5:

```
 "some string".truncate(5)
 => "so..."
```

notice that in this `N = 5` it includes the ellipsis characters, so you might need `N + 3` for the example you described.

Comment: Not a ruby method, a Rails method.